# How can we query the MS Graph API to access the Teams data folders at their storage location?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-api

The documentation for Teams indicates that the data is stored in various locations across the MS Azure systems. For example:

- One-to-one and Group chats are stored in Exchange, in "hidden folders" that are only accessible by an admin
- Files sent in chats are stored on OneDrive in a folder called "Microsoft Teams Chat
  Files"

Using the Graph Explorer, I have been able to query for the list of chat messages directly. But due to permission constraints in my app, I need to know how I can reach the actual storage location of these files for retrieval. **How do I query for and list the contents of the "hidden folders" in that store the chat messages?**

Comment: There is no API to access the chats stored in hidden folders. You can get chats using Graph API only. [Get chatMessage in a channel or chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT So even if we pull the list of folders for the user as if we are going through their Mail, it won't return the hidden folders that store the Chats?

Comment: Please go through [List mailFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request). Use includeHiddenFolders=true to include hidden mail folders in the response:

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to access the chats stored in hidden folders. You can get chats using Graph API only. [Get chatMessage in a channel or chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Please go through [List mailFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request). Use includeHiddenFolders=true to include hidden mail folders in the response.